# Prevent the onTriggered event on listview header in blackberry 10 cascades?

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have created the custom header in listview blackberry 10 qml. But the listview header also fired on OnTriggered event.

```
listItemComponents: [
    ListItemComponent {
    type: "header"
        Container {
            preferredWidth: 748
            layout: DockLayout {}

            Label {
                text: "Custom Header"
                horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Left
                verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                textStyle{
                    base:SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BigText
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the answer, implement the listview ontriggered function like below

```
onTriggered: {
                        if(indexPath!=0){
                        var selectedItem = dataModel.data(indexPath);
                        var newPage = nextPage.createObject();
                        navigationPane.push(newPage);
                    }
```

Comment: actually to skip headers, it should be: if (indexPath.length > 1) { ... }; headers have an indexPath.length == 1